# Make ComponentWillUnmount work before ComponentWillMount

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I have this code that look like this :

```
componentWillUnmount() {
        const {
            changeTableAttribute,
        } = this.props;

        changeTableAttribute({ key: 'loadingTable', value: true });
        changeTableAttribute({ key: 'page', value: 1 });
        changeTableAttribute({ key: 'status', value: '' });
        changeTableAttribute({ key: 'periode', value: 'now' });
        changeTableAttribute({ key: 'warehouse_id', value: 1 });
        changeTableAttribute({ key: 'limit', value: 10 });
        changeTableAttribute({ key: 'search', value: '' });
        changeTableAttribute({ key: 'sort_by', value: '' });
    }
```

Basically i want to reset the redux state by using dispatch (changeTableAttribute) to its original value when i move from one page to another. But the problem is the state reset after the componentWillMount from another page/component , so how can i wait componentWillUnmount till it finish doing its task and then move to componentWillMount from another component/page ? i know one of the solution to solve this problem is by separate the state in Redux , but that is not possible as i am not allowed to change the code create by other person.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ComponentDidMount in the second component

Comment: I think you are right , but unfortunately i don't have permission to change the other codes. And now i'm stuck with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, You should try to understand how lifeCycle methods work. `componentWillUnmount` will work only after the next component's `componentWillMount` executes. So you cannot do as you expect. `componentWillUnmount` executes as soon as `componentWillMount` finishes executing. If you want the behaviour as you have said, then try using `componentDidMount`. Hope it helps!. **Happy Coding!!**

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for the explanation , but unfortunately i don't have permission to change other codes that use componentWillMount to componentDidMount.

Comment: You mean, you don't have permission to read the next rendering component's codes? @ImanuelJodi

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better solution it is to unsubscribe from the data store ,

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    mydatastore.subscribe(this);
  }
  render() {
    ...
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    mydatastore.unsubscribe(this);
  }
}
```